# Bootstrap Datepicker not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, responsive, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker in a div. Everything works fine until i reduce the window's dimensions. 
The code is the following:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p> Pick a Date: </p>
  <div class="datepicker input-group" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <p>Choose a Campaign:</p>
   <select id="selectCampaign" class="form-control">
      <option value="opt1" id="opt1">opt1</option>
      <option value="opt2" id="opt2">opt2</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a class="btnSearch" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    });
});
```

Here's the "error":
[image: Here's the "error"]

Here's the normal app behaviour:
[image: Here's the normal app behaviour]

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the latest version of bootstrap. Otherwise, it should run as intended. Refer to my answer below. Hope this is what you're looking for.

### Edit

I think, the main mistake you're making is not providing an id for the datepicker.Only when the id is provided and called, the datepicker is going to become responsive. Check out the code snippet that I've modified.

Define an id for the datepicker as here below.

```
<div class="datepicker input-group" id='datetimepicker1' data-provide="datepicker">
```

### Datepicker code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'});
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-3">
  <p> Pick a Date: </p>
  <div class="datepicker input-group" id='datetimepicker1' data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <p>Choose a Campaign:</p>
   <select id="selectCampaign" class="form-control">
      <option value="opt1" id="opt1">opt1</option>
      <option value="opt2" id="opt2">opt2</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a class="btnSearch" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
```

**Hope it works now**

Comment: tried this "version" but it's not working, i get the same results as mine :v

Comment: @LucaStucchi But it seems to run on the code snippet. If you're facing any issues, could you let me know the exact problem that you're encountering?